# Como resolver erro "Cannot read property 'substring' of null"

Tags: javascript

Preciso exibir dados de um BD em uma área de filtros mas não estou conseguindo, ele somente funciona se uso um dos filtros, e no console apresenta o seguinte erro "Cannot read property 'substring' of null".

Código do controller:

```
  .filter('daterangeentrevistado', function () {
        return function (conversations, start_date, end_date) {
            var result = [];

        var start_date = start_date ? new Date(start_date.substring(start_date.length - 4, start_date.length) + "/" + start_date.substring(start_date.length - 7, start_date.length - 5) + "/" + start_date.substring(0, start_date.length == 10 ? 2 : 1)).getTime() : 0;
        var end_date = end_date ? new Date(end_date.substring(end_date.length - 4, end_date.length) + "/" + end_date.substring(end_date.length - 7, end_date.length - 5) + "/" + end_date.substring(0, end_date.length == 10 ? 2 : 1)).getTime() : new Date().getTime();


        if (conversations && conversations.length > 0) {
            $.each(conversations, function (index, conversation) {
                var conversationDate = new Date(conversation.datanascimento.substring(conversation.datanascimento.length - 4, conversation.datanascimento.length) + "/" + conversation.datanascimento.substring(conversation.datanascimento.length - 7, conversation.datanascimento.length - 5) + "/" + conversation.datanascimento.substring(0, conversation.datanascimento.length == 10 ? 2 : 1)).getTime();

                if (conversationDate >= start_date && conversationDate <= end_date) {

                    result.push(conversation);
                }
            });

            return result;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Preciso fazer com que todos as pessoas desse BD apareçam mesmo sem eu usar filtro

Comment: Recomendaria você renomear as variáveis `start_date` e `end_date` para diferenciá-las dos parâmetros passados na função de retorno e impedir qualquer tipo de conflito. Depois, você pode fazer uma verificação da variável `conversationDate`, aparentemente pode ser também a propriedade `conversation.datanascimento`.

Comment: Como posso realizar essa verificação?? Obrigado desde já!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, recomendo você renomear as variáveis `start_date` e `end_date` para não criar nenhum conflitos com os parâmetros passados para a função de retorno.  Para facilitar um pouco vamos renomear os parâmetros:

```
return function (conversations, start_date_param, end_date_param) {.....
```

Depois, fazemos a verificação em `conversation.datanascimento` assim como você realiza em outras variáveis também. Vamos criar uma variável para a `datanascimento` para tornar o substring mais legível:

```
var dataNascimento = conversation.datanascimento;
```

E então, fazemos a verificação:

```
if(dataNascimento) {
    var conversationDate = new Date(dataNascimento.substring(dataNascimento.length - 4, dataNascimento.length) + "/" + dataNascimento.substring(dataNascimento.length - 7, dataNascimento.length - 5) + "/" + dataNascimento.substring(0, dataNascimento.length == 10 ? 2 : 1)).getTime();
}
```

Aqui está seu código com todas as modificações que citei:

```
.filter('daterangeentrevistado', function () {

    return function (conversations, start_date_param, end_date_param) {

        var result = [];

        var start_date = start_date_param ? new Date(start_date_param.substring(start_date_param.length - 4, start_date_param.length) + "/" + start_date_param.substring(start_date_param.length - 7, start_date_param.length - 5) + "/" + start_date_param.substring(0, start_date_param.length == 10 ? 2 : 1)).getTime() : 0;
        var end_date = end_date_param ? new Date(end_date_param.substring(end_date_param.length - 4, end_date_param.length) + "/" + end_date_param.substring(end_date_param.length - 7, end_date_param.length - 5) + "/" + end_date_param.substring(0, end_date_param.length == 10 ? 2 : 1)).getTime() : new Date().getTime();

        if (conversations && conversations.length > 0) {
            $.each(conversations, function (index, conversation) {

                var dataNascimento = conversation.datanascimento;

                if(dataNascimento) {

                   var conversationDate = new Date(dataNascimento.substring(dataNascimento.length - 4, dataNascimento.length) + "/" + dataNascimento.substring(dataNascimento.length - 7, dataNascimento.length - 5) + "/" + dataNascimento.substring(0, dataNascimento.length == 10 ? 2 : 1)).getTime();

                    if (conversationDate >= start_date && conversationDate <= end_date) {
                        result.push(conversation);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    alert("Aparentemente conversation.datanascimento (dataNascimento) é nulo: " + dataNascimento);
                }

            });

            return result;
        }

    };

});
```

Comment: Caaaraaaaaa, muito obrigado, funcionou. Me ajudou muito!!!